# Aptana Studio 3 - Git commands(commit, push) in Toolbar

Tags: aptana3

I just installed the latest Aptana Studio 3, imported a project from an existing folder and started to change files. I can right click and use the Team commands to commit and push, they work fine. I would like to have these functions easier to access from buttons located in the Toolbar.

I tried Right Click on Toolbar -> Customize Perspective. The Team option is enabled in Command Group Availability and also selected in Tool Bar Visibility. However, in Tool Bar Visibility, the single option listed under Team is Synchronize.

Any advice on how to have Commit and Push on the Toolbar? (I'm on a Mac, if that makes any difference)